# Obtain Pod DNS Name Programmatically

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a statefulset with 3 members. They are accessible from inside the cluster with something like:

```
podname-{0..n}.service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

I'm using the Kubernetes API from a Controller. I just created the Statefulset with:

```go
import (
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    appsv1 "k8s.io/api/apps/v1"
)
...

s := appsv1.StatefulSet{ /* some data */ }
kubernetes.AppsV1().StatefulSets(nameSpace).Create(s)
```

Let's assume everything worked correctly, and after a few minutes I have 3 running Pods. How can I get the Pod DNS entries for the newly created Pods?

I know I can build the DNS with:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d.%s.%s.svc.cluster.local", s.Name, idx, service, S.Namespace)
```

But I'm finding some issues:

1. I will have to calculate the index depending on the amount of replicas
2. I need to know about the service name used for this `StatefulSet`
3. I'm assuming the cluster domain is `cluster.local` which is not necessarily true

What I think it should exists (but I'm not sure if it really exists), is an API, that given a StatefulSet will allow me to know the DNS names of the Replicas that were created. Does an API like this exists?

Answer (score 2):

When you create the headless `Service` with the `StatefulSet`, it should create DNS SRV entries. You can query that to get a list of all host names of the pods corresponding to the headless `Service` without knowing the number. For example, if using Python you can do:

```
>>> import dns
>>> for item in dns.resolver.query('your-app-name-headless', 'SRV'): item
...
<DNS IN SRV rdata: 10 25 0 2555bb89.your-app-name-headless.your-project.svc.cluster.local.>
<DNS IN SRV rdata: 10 25 0 830bdb18.your-app-name-headless.your-project.svc.cluster.local.>
<DNS IN SRV rdata: 10 25 0 aeb532de.your-app-name-headless.your-project.svc.cluster.local.>
<DNS IN SRV rdata: 10 25 0 a432c21f.your-app-name-headless.your-project.svc.cluster.local.>
```

See:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services

Comment: how do you get an IP from those items?  I'm trying to use them as bootstrap servers for a Kafka consumer, but I can't get the right strings to pass...

Answer (score 1):

Event sniffing what you need is pretty much exactly how KubeDNS works.

So [code here](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go) of old and simple way.
take a look `podWatchFunc` method.
So here short example of code

```
func podWatchFunc(c *kubernetes.Clientset, ns string, s labels.Selector) func(options meta.ListOptions) (watch.Interface, error) {
    return func(options meta.ListOptions) (watch.Interface, error) {
        if s != nil {
            options.LabelSelector = s.String()
        }
        w, err := c.CoreV1().Pods(ns).Watch(options)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return w, nil
    }
}
```

Another good and recommended way in [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#programmatic-access-to-the-api)

```
 import (
   "fmt"
   "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes"
   "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/pkg/api/v1"
   "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/tools/clientcmd"
)
...
   // uses the current context in kubeconfig
   config, _ := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "path to kubeconfig")
   // creates the clientset
   clientset, _:= kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
   // access the API to list pods
   pods, _:= clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(v1.ListOptions{})
   fmt.Printf("There are %d pods in the cluster\n", len(pods.Items))
...
```

[full code](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go)

You also may understand that dns is separate k8s service, not part of cluster services. So find ip/host and call your dns endpoint
[For details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/)
if you use default naming policy and coredsn or dns-masq service.
You also can have domain name from [pod metadata](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ObjectMeta.md) name or selflink

```
    metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-04-01T13:45:01Z
  generateName: client-deployment-f8454db47-
  labels:
    app: client
    pod-template-hash: "940108603"
  name: client-deployment-f8454db47-5gk64
  namespace: novaposhta
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: client-deployment-f8454db47
    uid: d833ef0f-35b2-11e8-9278-42010a840112
  resourceVersion: "73550"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/novaposhta/pods/client-deployment-f8454db47-5gk64
```

Comment: I can get the PodList, but what about each Pod's DNS name, like `pod-0.service.default.svc.cluster.local`?

Comment: As i understand K8s can't give you exact dns Name through it's api, you need get pod info(https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/01eabee36475d015bbae57ff4f5d09492fe9fbe9/listers/core/v1/pod.go) and then ask dns service for it's name

Comment: Another way, take ip:host from https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/2c3457d98528c895e6841c8bc20f07fc5f388f82/kubernetes/docs/V1PodStatus.md
And then find domain name.